# Producing image by running highcharts-convert.js on phantomjs

Tags: javascript, highcharts, phantomjs

I'm new to highcharts-convert & phantomjs and I was trying to run these to obtain image on serverside.

While I was working on it, there was a tiny rounded edges on each corner of the image..

(damn.. stackoverflow doesn't allow me to upload an image..)

I'm not sure which attribute is causing it..

If anyone have any clue, please let me know.

Thank you for reading :)

(Also I went to official highchart forum and apparently it went down and suggested to post in here..)

Comment: You will probably need to include more detail to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

The option you're looking for is http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.borderRadius.

Comment: Please share the snippet used. Here's what I am using:

{
"infile":"{xAxis: {categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']},series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]}]};",
"callback":"function(chart) {chart.renderer.arc(200, 150, 100, 50, -Math.PI, 0).attr({fill : '#FCFFC5',stroke : 'black','stroke-width' : 1}).attr({borderWidth: 0}).attr({borderRadius: 0}).add();}",
"constr":"Chart",
"outfile":"//tmp//chart.png"
}